# How to move a primefaces iframe lightbox?

Tags: jsf, iframe, primefaces

I have to make a draggable/moveable lightbox iframe

**lightBox code:**

```
<p:lightBox id="draggable" iframe="true" width="910px" height="500px" style="overflow:none" widgetVar="dlg" iframeTitle="flight">        
   <h:outputLink value="/airProject/flightBooking.xhtml" title="flight" styleClass="LinkButton">  
   </h:outputLink>                  
</p:lightBox>
```

**Tried this(for moving)**

```
<p:draggable for="draggable" />
```

and also this too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 });
</script>
```

But these are moving button not iframe popup. So how do drag/move the iframe lighbox popup as we move p:dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your lightBox's widgetVar is: `lightBoxWV`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       PF('lightBoxWV').panel.draggable()
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.